# display largest data value in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i'm a newbie on mysql. i want to display the largest number of votes in the table as well as the candidate number, last name, first name, and middle name. but when i use the max() function to select the largest number of votes. the largest vote is selected but the candidate number, last name, first name and middle name are the default first values in the database...  here's the example:

candidate table:

```
candidate no    last name  first name   middle name  position    votes 
038-001         banchero   chris        ace          president      99
038-002         castro     jayson       texk         president     100
```

what i want to display:

```
038-002           castro   jayson          texk       president   100
```

my problem is that the first row is always displayed only the highest votes are display. like this:

```
(038-001 banchero chris ace 100)
```

thanks. I would really appreciate any help. :)

Comment: Where did you get the name `Requesto Dan Martin`?

Comment: If you don't care about ties, then you can use `select ... from ... order by votes desc limit 1`.  If ties are needed, use the solution below.

Comment: it was a typo error. it should be castro jayson texk president 100. my mistake. hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from tablename
where votes = (select max(votes) from tablename)
```

Will return the row with max number of votes. (And both rows if it's a tie.)